# c# Update SharePoint User Property CSOM + Pnp Framework

Tags: c#, sharepoint, csom

When we migrated our project from .net 4.7 to .Net core 3.1 I had to find an alternative to **SharePointOnlineCredentials** class.

To generate my ClientContext I'm now use AuthenticationManager from Pnp.Framework package.

However I'm not able to update Sharepoint user properties anymore.
I get the error:

> 'Access denied. You do not have permission to perform this action or access this resource.'

Whenever I use the SharePoint admin user (like before) or a registered AAD app with Uer.ReadWrite.All permission.

My test SharePoint admin user account:

```
using(var am = PnP.Framework.AuthenticationManager.CreateWithCredentials(clientId, userName, password))
using (var clientContext = am.GetContext(adminSiteUrl))
{
    var peopleManager = new PeopleManager(clientContext);
    var personProperties = peopleManager.GetPropertiesFor(accountName);
    clientContext.Load(personProperties);
    clientContext.ExecuteQuery();

    peopleManager.SetSingleValueProfileProperty(personProperties.AccountName, "officeKey", "MTR");

    clientContext.ExecuteQuery(); //Throws the 'Access Denied' exception here
}
```

My test with registered client app (using a certificate)

```
using (var am = new PnP.Framework.AuthenticationManager(clientId, certificatePath, certificatePassword, tenant))
using (var clientContext = am.GetContext(adminSiteUrl))
{
    var peopleManager = new PeopleManager(clientContext);
    var personProperties = peopleManager.GetPropertiesFor(accountName);
    clientContext.Load(personProperties);
    clientContext.ExecuteQuery();

    peopleManager.SetSingleValueProfileProperty(personProperties.AccountName, "officeKey", "MTR");

    clientContext.ExecuteQuery(); //Throws the 'Access Denied' exception here
}
```

Note: My registered app client in AAD has all the SharePoint API permissions.

My project is referencing packages:

- Microsoft.SharePointOnline.CSOM (16.1.20912.12000)
- Pnp.Framework (1.2.0)

Answer (score 1):

I finally managaged to get it working by registering an app in SharePoint (instead of AAD).
You first need to register the app by creating a clientId and clientSecret: `https://<tenant>-admin.sharepoint.com/_layouts/15/appregnew.aspx`
Then you need to grant permissions: `https://<tenant>-admin.sharepoint.com/_layouts/15/appinv.aspx`
You need to give these permissions:

```
<AppPermissionRequests AllowAppOnlyPolicy="true">
  <AppPermissionRequest Scope="http://sharepoint/content/tenant" Right="FullControl" />
  <AppPermissionRequest Scope="http://sharepoint/social/tenant" Right="FullControl" />
</AppPermissionRequests>
```

You'll then be able to get user properties:

```
using (var clientContext = new PnP.Framework.AuthenticationManager().GetACSAppOnlyContext(siteUrl, appId, appSecret))
{
    var peopleManager = new PeopleManager(clientContext);
    var personProperties = peopleManager.GetPropertiesFor(accountName);
    clientContext.Load(personProperties);
    clientContext.ExecuteQuery();

    peopleManager.SetSingleValueProfileProperty(personProperties.AccountName, "officeKey", "MTR");

    clientContext.ExecuteQuery(); //Throws the 'Access Denied' exception here
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**Try using this nuget packages (02/03/2023) Microsoft.SharePointOnline.CSOM and Pnp.Framework and then...**

```
enter code here

using Microsoft.SharePoint.Client;
using PnP.Framework;
using System.IO;
using System.Net;

...

try
{
    string sSiteSP = txtSitioSP.Text;
    string sUrlFile = txtUrl.Text;
    string sUser = txtUsuario.Text + "@fnd.gob.mx";
    string sPass = txtContrasenia.Text;
    string sSave = txtFile.Text;
    System.Security.SecureString ssPass = new();
    foreach (char c in sPass.ToCharArray())
        ssPass.AppendChar(c);

    var authManager = PnP.Framework.AuthenticationManager.CreateWithCredentials(sUser, ssPass);
    var ctx = authManager.GetContext(sSiteSP);

    Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.File spFile = ctx.Web.GetFileByUrl(sUrlFile);
    ClientResult<Stream> crstream = spFile.OpenBinaryStream();

    ctx.Load(spFile);
    lblMensaje.Text = "Iniciando descarga";
    ctx.ExecuteQuery();

    using (FileStream fs = System.IO.File.OpenWrite(Path.Combine(sSave, spFile.Name)))
        crstream.Value.CopyTo(fs);
    lblMensaje.Text = "Descarga completa " + (spFile.Length / 1024) + " kb";

}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
}
```

Comment: Remember that Stack Overflow isn't just intended to solve the immediate problem, but also to help future readers find solutions to similar problems, which requires understanding the underlying code. This is especially important for members of our community who are beginners, and not familiar with the syntax. Given that, **can you [edit] your answer to include an explanation of what you're doing** and why you believe it is the best approach?